# How to check if APC caching is working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have APC set up and installed in Magento. I was wondering if there is a way I can confirm it is caching and working correctly. The pages seem to be loading fine, but I need to verify.

Answer (score 0):

if you have dedicated server or vps, then you better upgrade php to the latest version and use [ZendOpcache](https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache), it can be installed as a package or compiled in with `pecl`.

APC cache was discontinued, and available now as [APCu](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu)

this is how to get all modules and php information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

or from shell: `php -m | grep apc`

and here some other answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393626/how-do-i-know-if-any-php-caching-is-enabled
https://serverfault.com/questions/165792/where-is-apc-php